# when I run p.start(), I got TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        # num_processes = 4
        # NOTE: this is required for the ``fork`` method to work
        torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
        cnn.share_memory()
        processes = []
        for rank in range(args.num_processes):
            p = mu.Process(target=train.train, args=(rank, train_iter, dev_iter, cnn, args,))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
```

when I run `p.start()`,have a error in here,The following is the error message,anyone can help me,thanks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/workspace/pycharmworkspace/cnn-text-classification-pytorch-update/main.py", line 144, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\bamtercelboo\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

Comment: Looks like maybe `train.train` is not a function?

Comment: wow,but train.train is a function

Comment: thanks for your help, if I change code like follow   ,it can be run，but train.train is function really.and this code not limit the number of process.                                            p = mu.Process(target=train.train(rank, train_iter, dev_iter, cnn, args))

Comment: `p = mu.Process(target=train.train(rank, train_iter, dev_iter, cnn, args))` looks like you are either calling the function in the `target` argument, or (more likely) `train.train` is a generator that is returning a function. Can you post the code for `train.train`?

Comment: I have solve it yesterday， thanks for your help